# Class constructer from agregation link

Tags: c++, oop

I am pretty much new to OOP and C++ but have a project of "graph traversing" (sorry if there's a more formal term).

I am at the very beginning of the project where I have to initialize an 2D grid composed of cases.

I first thought of creating a class Case with 2D-position and a boolean state (occupied of free) as attributes, and a Grid class with a vector of vector of Cases representing the grid.

First I wondered if I'm going in the right direction on terms of Object-oriented programming, and if so I wondered how to initialize the grid in the constructor.

So far I have this for the Case class header :

```
class case_tab{

int x,y;

bool state; 



public:

case_tab(int x_param, int y_param, bool state_param);
};
```

And the constructor :

```
case_tab::case_tab(int x_param, int y_param, bool state_param)

:x(x_param),y(y_param),state(state_param)
{}
```

But the problem comes for the grid constructor (named tableau, here you can see the header):

```
class tableau
{

int X, Y;



public:

std::vector<std::vector<case_tab>> tab;

tableau(int X_param, int Y_param);
};
```

Where I don't know how to initialize the grid (tableau) as a grid of free Cases disposed correctly.

I'm pretty sure this is of very basic difficulty but I can't find how to do so, and wonder if it doesn't come from my structure choice in the first place.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you declared the attribute `tab`, it will be initialized by default. So you just have to do two loops so as to fill it. Here is a proposal:

```
tableau::tableau(int X_param, int Y_param)
        : X(X_param), Y(Y_param) {
    for(int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        std::vector<case_tab> row;
        row.reserve(Y);
        for(int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
            row.emplace_back(i, j, false);
        }
        tab.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

`emplace_back` generates and adds `case_tab` objects by calling the constructor that you defined, and `reserve` allocates memory for the initialized objects.

You should also change `tab` visibility to `private`, so as to prevent adding unexpected items to it.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks.
I was searching for a way to initialize the tab in the same way as X and Y are and couldn't find a way. I should have thought of how you did it.